# Environment.NewLine equivalent for compact framework 2.0

Tags: c#, compact-framework

What is the best practice for inserting a newline character into a string in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the Compact Framework not support `Environment.NewLine`? Ah well. You can just use `"\r\n"` - if you *know* you're on the compact framework, it's not like you're running on Mono where the default new line may be different :)

You could always create your own string property:

```
public static class PortableEnvironment
{
    public static string NewLine
    {
        get
        {
#if COMPACT_FRAMEWORK
            return "\r\n";
#else
            return Environment.NewLine;
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably kind of gross, but I guess you can look at whether `Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString().StartsWith("Win")` and presume `\r\n` is correct in that situation. :-)

Comment: There are bigger problems than that in CF.  Size of the screen jumps to mind.  Trying to be agnostic about the hardware/OS is a lossy proposition.  WM's downfall, gotta control the hardware.